# Is the following proposition true?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I just started analysis and I'm struggling to get my head around the concept of

So if A is true (which it is in the case) and B is F (which it is in this case), then the proposition will be false?

Comment: True. It will be false.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your understanding is spot on: An implication $P \rightarrow Q$ is false *if and only if* the premise ($P$) is true and the conclusion $(Q)$is false.

That's what you have here. Hence the proposition is false.